# Gallery thumbnails very small

Tags: theme-development, images, gallery

When I use the standard WordPress gallery, I get very small thumbnails in the content:

[image]

Since there is lots of space in the content, I would like to display bigger images. How can I do that?
There is no specific gallery code added in the theme.

Answer (score 4):

Either use one of the other built-in image sizes, for instance

```
[gallery size="medium"]
```

or "large" or "full",

and/or customize the sizes for "thumbnail", "medium", "large" under `Settings > Media`,

or [add a new image size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and use it

```
[gallery size="newsize"]
```